# RichTextBox SelectionStart exceeds the TextLength (Winform c#)

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

This problem is driving me crazy. I have a RTB and I capture the last word entered in the RTB when the space key is pressed and replace it with some suggested word as seen in VS intellisense popup. Everything was working fine except when I pasted text with hyperlinks/tables the RTB.SelectionStart property becomes bigger than RTB.Text.Length. From RTB.SelectionStart property I capture the characters entered towards left till a space is found and the reverse it to get the last word entered. but I can't do that if I paste some hyperlink text and starts writing some word; because now the RTB.SelectionStart becomes bigger than RTB.Text.Length; I can't use RTB.Text.Substring method to capture the characters( towards left)

How to correctly get the current cursor position in such case?

edit:

```
private string GetLastWord()
    {string word = "";
        int pos = rtfText.SelectionStart;
      //  int length = rtfText.Text.Length;
       // if (pos > length) pos = length;

            if (pos >= 1)
            {
                string tmp = "";
                var f = new char();

                while (f != ' ' && f != '-' && f != 10 && pos > 0)
                {
                    pos--;
                    tmp = rtfText.Text.Substring(pos, 1);
                    f = tmp[0];
                    word += f;
                }

                char[] ca = word.ToCharArray();
                Array.Reverse(ca);
                word = new String(ca);
            }
            // MessageBox.Show(word + ":" + word.Length);
            return word;
   }
```

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: post your code. sample input and the output you expect

Comment: What event handler are you using to call that method?

Comment: Actually I am using KeyPress; But I put the method on a button click even then also RTB.SelectionStart is biigger than RTB.Text.Length ( plz see by yourself by pasting some hyperlink texts @MattR

Comment: give me any sample that you are putting in your rich text box

Comment: @jeff when I've tried it works fine, I pasted a link to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18377103/richtextbox-selectionstart-exceeds-the-textlength-winform-c?noredirect=1#comment26985831_18377103) and it came up with the last word being c?noredirect=1#comment26985831_18377103.  No exceptions thrown.   THis will seem daft but could you provide some example text of anything you had in the RTB before pasting a link and anything else you're trying?

Comment: @MattR, Do you find RTB.Text.Length and RTB.SelectionStart the same if you paste hyperlink text? If I don't get the startindex of the last entered word I can't replace it properly with the suggested word. The thing which trouble me most is RTB.SelectionStart becomes bigger than RTB.Text.Lengthand thatz why I used the commented out lines ( line 4 and 5) to fix it, but that doesn't give me the start index of the last entered word so that I can replace it with the suggested word

Comment: @jeff for the URL I posted in my last comment the RTB.Text.Length is 141 and the RTB.SelectionStart is also 141, so they match.  Can you provide a sample piece of text that doesn't work?

Comment: I got it; the problem is only if I paste hyperlink text written in MS Word. Please try a text linke 'Test' and hyperlink it to some file in your PC using MS WORD and see @MattR. If you want I can give you a sample project also. Same thing applies for WORD made tables also. just see for youself

Comment: Ok if I'm following you correctly I've created a hyperlink in Word with Test as the text to display.  When I copy / paste it into the RTB the value is `Test <C:\Users\xxx\Documents\my file.txt>`.  The `RTB.Selection` start is 49, and the `TextLength` is also 49.  And the code returns the selected word as: `code.txt>`

Comment: @MattR, that's very strange. Can you show me the code? Because I am using the following in a winform with one RTB, two buttons. First button click:  int pos = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
            int len = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
            MessageBox.Show("pos:" + pos + ":" + "length:" + len);    seconde button click:  MessageBox.Show(GetLastWord());
            MessageBox.Show("pos:" + richTextBox1.SelectionStart + ":" + "length:" + richTextBox1.Text.Length);

Comment: @MattR ,I think you are using RTB.TextLength instead of RTB.Text.Length. But then how do you use the GetLastWord method I put earlier in my question because tmp = rtfText.Text.Substring(pos, 1); will give startIndex can't be larger than length of string error!!

Comment: @jeff you're correct, I didn't notice the . between Text and Length, however the results are the same. I shall retry now. As for how I'm calling it, I have a button click (as you initially suggested) which calls the method. I can then see the returned output.

Comment: @Jeff I've added my code down as an answer for readability.

Comment: @MattR I ran your code but got startIndex cannot be larger than length of string error !!! with a simple hyperlink 'Test'

Comment: Hmm this certainly is starting to seem like a puzzler.  Can you put up all of your code and I will run it on my machine (obviously taking out anything confidential etc).

Comment: @MattR, sure thatz is what I was thinking.where to send it... your email? or mediafire.com ?

Comment: @jeff hmm not sure, let's give mediafire a try and hopefully it won't be blocked here.  Or if there isn't a lot just add the actual to your question.

Comment: @MattR, Oh, I got the problem, I was using an ExtendedRichTextBox control derived from RichTextBox which was causing that error.(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22783/Advanced-Text-Editor-with-Ruler). If I use normal richtextbox then it works as expected

Comment: @jeff well that's certainly good news. :-)